# Fill image in parent container bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, background-image

I have an banner image that is 1920 x 1300 which I want to display within a container **or** jumbotron which is 800px height.

How can i fit the image in so that it is also responsive and so is the text ontop of it?

```
<div class="container-fluid>
  <div class="image-container">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>

CSS:

.image-container{
  background-image: url("..images/background.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  height:800px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Or would it be a better idea to re-size the image?

Comment: It might be only me, but I cannot really understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you provide a JSFiddle or codepen to work with your code and describe the desired outcome a bit more as well please.

Comment: Are you sure the image path is correct? or url(../images/background.jpg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use an html `<img>` instead of an css background.

I've made an JSFiddle of how I would do that.

Set the inner content inside the `<div class="image-container">` and set it absolute.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b49rc4hc/3/).